# Convert UL LI into accordion without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, jqlite

I want to convert a UL LI structure into accordion but without using Jquery.

[image: Accordion]

I am using Angular JS, that's why I don't want to use Jquery and no Bootsrap either as I have my data which gets displayed in UL LI structure only. Please help me convert UL LI to accordion.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "accordion", cause there are many different things named "accordion".

Answer (score 2):

I found this link which create an accordion with HTML + CSS only

https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/ihlDf

**CSS**

```
$white: rgba(254,255,250,1)
$grey: rgba(220,231,235,1)
$red: rgba(255,104,115,1)
$black: rgba(48,69,92,0.8)
$sans: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif

.transition
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out

.flipIn
  animation: flipdown 0.5s ease both

.no-select
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
  -webkit-touch-callout: none
  -webkit-user-select: none
  -khtml-user-select: none
  -moz-user-select: none
  -ms-user-select: none
  user-select: none

html
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  perspective: 900
  overflow-y: scroll
  background-color: $grey
  font-family: $sans
  color: $black

body
  min-height: 0
  display: inline-block
  position: relative
  left: 50%
  margin: 90px 0
  transform: translate( -50% , 0 )
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 $red inset
  background-color: $white
  max-width: 450px
  padding: 30px

  @media ( max-width:550px )
    box-sizing: border-box
    transform: translate( 0 , 0 )
    max-width: 100%
    min-height: 100%
    margin: 0
    left: 0

h1 , h2
  color: $red

h1
  text-transform: uppercase
  font-size: 36px
  line-height: 42px
  letter-spacing: 3px
  font-weight: 100
  @extend .flipIn

h2
  font-size: 26px
  line-height: 34px
  font-weight: 300
  letter-spacing: 1px
  display: block
  background-color: $white
  margin: 0
  cursor: pointer
  @extend .no-select

p
  color: $black
  font-size: 17px
  line-height: 26px
  letter-spacing: 1px
  position: relative
  overflow: hidden
  max-height: 800px
  @extend .transition
  opacity: 1
  transform: translate( 0 , 0 )  
  margin-top: 14px
  z-index: 2

ul
  list-style: none
  perspective: 900
  padding: 0
  margin: 0

  li
    position: relative
    padding: 0
    margin: 0
    padding-bottom: 4px
    padding-top: 18px
    border-top: 1px dotted $grey
    @extend .flipIn

    &:nth-of-type(1)
      animation-delay: 0.5s

    &:nth-of-type(2)
      animation-delay: 0.75s

    &:nth-of-type(3)
      animation-delay: 1.0s

    &:last-of-type
      padding-bottom: 0

    i
      position: absolute
      transform: translate( -6px , 0 )
      margin-top: 16px
      right: 0

      &:before , &:after
        content: ""
        @extend .transition
        position: absolute
        background-color: $red
        width: 3px
        height: 9px

      &:before
        transform: translate( -2px , 0 ) rotate( 45deg )

      &:after
        transform: translate( 2px , 0 ) rotate( -45deg )

    input[type=checkbox]
      position: absolute
      cursor: pointer
      width: 100%
      height: 100%
      z-index: 1
      opacity: 0

      &:checked
        &~p
          margin-top: 0
          max-height: 0
          opacity: 0
          transform: translate( 0 , 50% )

        &~i
          &:before
            transform: translate( 2px , 0 ) rotate( 45deg )

          &:after
            transform: translate( -2px , 0 ) rotate( -45deg )

@keyframes flipdown
  0%
    opacity: 0
    transform-origin: top center
    transform: rotateX(-90deg)
  5%
    opacity: 1
  80%
    transform: rotateX(8deg)
  83%
    transform: rotateX(6deg)
  92%
    transform: rotateX(-3deg)
  100%
    transform-origin: top center
    transform: rotateX(0deg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block }

body { line-height: 1 }

ol, ul { list-style: none }


.nav a, .nav label {
  display: block;
 padding: .85rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #151515;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #1d1d1d;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in;
  transition: all .25s ease-in;
}

.nav a:focus, .nav a:hover, .nav label:focus, .nav label:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: #030303;
}

.nav label { cursor: pointer; }

/**
 * Styling first level lists items
 */

.group-list a, .group-list label {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  background: #252525;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #373737;
}

.group-list a:focus, .group-list a:hover, .group-list label:focus, .group-list label:hover { background: #131313; }

/**
 * Styling second level list items
 */

.sub-group-list a, .sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 4rem;
  background: #353535;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #474747;
}

.sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-group-list a:hover, .sub-group-list label:focus, .sub-group-list label:hover { background: #232323; }

/**
 * Styling third level list items
 */

.sub-sub-group-list a, .sub-sub-group-list label {
  padding-left: 6rem;
  background: #454545;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px #575757;
}

.sub-sub-group-list a:focus, .sub-sub-group-list a:hover, .sub-sub-group-list label:focus, .sub-sub-group-list label:hover { background: #333333; }

/**
 * Hide nested lists
 */

.group-list, .sub-group-list, .sub-sub-group-list {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul { /* reset the height when checkbox is checked */
max-height: 1000px; }

/**
 * Rotating chevron icon
 */

label > span {
  float: right;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .65s ease;
  transition: transform .65s ease;
}

.nav__list input[type=checkbox]:checked + label > span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav__list">
      <li>
        <input id="group-1" type="checkbox" hidden="">
        <label for="group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
        <ul class="group-list">
          <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
          <li>
            <input id="sub-group-1" type="checkbox" hidden="">
            <label for="sub-group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
            <ul class="sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li>
                <input id="sub-sub-group-1" type="checkbox" hidden="">
                <label for="sub-sub-group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Third level</label>
                <ul class="sub-sub-group-list">
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <input id="group-2" type="checkbox" hidden="">
      <label for="group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
      <ul class="group-list">
        <li>
        </li><li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <input id="sub-group-2" type="checkbox" hidden="">
        <label for="sub-group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li>
            <input id="sub-sub-group-2" type="checkbox" hidden="">
            <label for="sub-sub-group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Third level</label>
            <ul class="sub-sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <input id="group-3" type="checkbox" hidden="">
      <label for="group-3"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
      <ul class="group-list">
        <li>
        </li><li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <input id="sub-group-3" type="checkbox" hidden="">
        <label for="sub-group-3"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li>
            <input id="sub-sub-group-3" type="checkbox" hidden="">
            <label for="sub-sub-group-3"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Third level</label>
            <ul class="sub-sub-group-list">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <input id="group-4" type="checkbox" hidden="">
      <label for="group-4"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> First level</label>
      <ul class="group-list">
        <li>
        </li><li><a href="#">1st level item</a></li>
        <input id="sub-group-4" type="checkbox" hidden="">
        <label for="sub-group-4"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Second level</label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```